# Getting Json using Axios and iterating over data in ReactStrap Table

Tags: reactjs, axios, reactstrap

I am trying to get data from `jsonplaceholder` via `axios` and iterate over that data and put that data into a reactstrap table. I am getting the error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`. I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    const data = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(response =>
        this.data = response.data,
        this.data.forEach((item) => {
          <tr>
            <td>{item.userId}</td>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.title}</td>
            <td>{item.completed}</td>
          </tr>
        })
      )
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  User ID
                </th>
                <th>
                  ID
                </th>
                <th>
                  Title
                </th>
                <th>
                  Completed
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                data
              }
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The error is where I try to create the table row `<tr>` tags in my `data` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lifecycle methods to load your data from API and store them in a state and render them when the state is updated.

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          todos: this.data
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { todos = [] } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {todos.length ? 
              todos.map(todo => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{todo.userId}</td>
                  <td>{todo.id}</td>
                  <td>{todo.title}</td>
                  <td>{todo.completed}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
              : 
              (<tr>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>
              </tr>)
            }
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Right! Been using over stuff too much lately. I got a `unexpected token` error with the `todos = []`. Any clue why that may be?

Comment: There seems to be some errors with this solution, I changed the todos variable to `todos:[]` and fixed that token issue, but I am now getting `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` with axios for some reason

Comment: If you import `axios` at the top of the file, you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: I have imported it, but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` around the `tbody` area

Comment: Probably, API response is not right. Try destructuring safely like this `const { todos = [] } = this.state;`

Comment: Yeah it's not getting something right. I am just seeing "User ID ID Title Completed
- - - -"

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here:

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({
    todos: response.data, // you have it as this.data not response
  });
});
```